# Downloading Excel files with Django and Angular2

Tags: python, angularjs, django, excel, filesaver.js

I have a project in which I save files in SMB folder and use Django for the backside and Angular 2 for the front side. I have successfully managed to download the .csv files, but when the .xls file is downloaded, it is corrupted. The lines in the file look like this:

> Admin-Grisham
>   B�a�=���=o'��x<�*8X@�"��1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1�?�Arial1��Arial1�$�Arial1���Arial1���Calibri1�

This is my views.py file:

```
 '''Download file'''
def get(self, request, file_name):

    bicloudreposervice = BiCloudRepoService()

    file_obj = bicloudreposervice.get_user_file(request.user.email, file_name)
    file_path = file_obj.name

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as tmp:

        if 'xls' in file_name:
            resp = HttpResponse(tmp, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8')
        else:
            resp = HttpResponse(tmp, content_type='application/text;charset=UTF-8')

        resp['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % file_name

    self.logger.debug('Downloading file')

    return resp
```

The relevant function in the service file in typescript looks like this:

```
  downloadFile(fileName: string){
     let headers = this.headers;

     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     return this.http.get(this.connectorsUrl+'download-file/' + fileName + '/', options)
                .map(res => res)
                .catch(this.utils.handleError);
  }
```

And the component file:

```
  import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
   ...

  downloadFile(name){
   this.connectorsService.downloadFile(name).subscribe(
   res => {this.successDownloadFile(res, name);},
   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
   ()=> {});
 }

 successDownloadFile(res: any, name: String){

  this.showLoader = false;
  let blob;

  blob = new Blob([res._body], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});

  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, name.toString());
}
```

The corresponding html file:

```
...
<div (click)="downloadFile(file.name)">
    <i class="material-icons">file_download</i>
</div>
...
```

I use the external library FileSaver, but I have tried also with creating an URL object from the Blob, and window.open in Angular, but the file still looks the same. 
I have tried   `content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8'` in views.py and also  `{type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});` when creating the Blob in Angular.

What can I be doing wrong? Maybe I should handle the file differently in Django?
Thank you in advance for your help.